# Undelegating on Galleon wallet

Tags: baking

I want to un-delegate so that I can send XTZ to another wallet address. On Galleon Wallet, it seems that the only option is to "change" delegates, because when I leave the "new delegate" address blank, it will not let me complete the operation. Can someone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don’t need to « undelegate » prior to « redelegate ». Just point your contract to the new baker and this will work. Similarly, you do not need to undelegate to transfert the tokens. You are in control of funds you can just transfert them.

Comment: No, I want to un-delegate so that I can transfer all XTZ to another address.

Comment: @Tri you do not need to undelegate to transfert the tokens. You are in control of funds you can just transfert them.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is quite simple - this is good Tezos! Start a new delegation with a new address and transfer tokens from the old address to the new one. Everything will happen without loss of rewards!

Answer (score 0):

did you manage to do this? I want to do the same thing, move all my Tezos to my Ledger and delegate to the same baker if possible. I don't understand these answers:

@Ezy What does "Just point your contract to the new baker" mean? I want the same baker but I want to store my XTZ on a different wallet, i.e. Ledger instead of galleon or tezbox. Its like the XTZ is stuck.

@Tezosbakes What do you mean "Start a new delegation with a new address"? What new address? New baker? 'New' as in 'other' address? Like my ledger address or? "transfer tokens from the old address to the new one", ok, are we talking about from the baker or from the galleon address or?

The answers here do not explain it properly. I setup a stupid tezbox, which i've imported into Galleon, so when I try send the tokens to my ledger wallet from Galleon Wallet, I get this error:

```
cannot read property 'signOperation' of null
```

Why is there no simple: Stop delegating / withdraw delegation / pause and move funds functionality? They've tried to make it so simple, they've actually made it complicated.

Pls halp

Comment: @Ezy is saying that you don't need to transfer your Tezos to delegate to another baker, you also don't have to cancel your delegation when you want to move your Tezos!

Comment: IF you want to move your coins to a ledger, just do the following: 1. transfer coins to ledger, but leave 0,0001 Tezos in your old wallet. 2. delegate your ledger address to the baker of your choice. 3. After 30-40 days or so, check your old address to transfer the baking rewards that accumulated there to your ledger wallet. (your old address will accumulate staking rewards for the coins you had delegated in the last 7-12 cycles since there is a delay between delegating and receiving rewards!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, trying to empty an address that was delegated. The error was:

> Emptying an implicit delegated account is not allowed.

Although not ideal, a quick workaround was to leave some dust (0.01 XTZ) behind in the address.